# How to get Swagger UI in SpringBoot (404 error)

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm trying to add Swagger UI to my REST Api but I can't find swagger ui path or there is a problem with it. Because when I check the paths where swagger ui must be I see the 404 error and I see

```
No mapping for GET /swagger-ui/index.html
```

error like that.

My pom.xml file:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

</project>
```

My swagger ui config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SpringFoxConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Bean
    public Docket swagger() {
        return new Docket(SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

My application file:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@SpringBootApplication


public class FlightticketappApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FlightticketappApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you get any solution? I'm getting the same issue on Kotlin with Springboot, the "/v2/api-docs" URL  works well, but when I try the "/swagger-ui.html" or any variation of it, I still receiving the "not found" advise

Answer (score 0):

The default URL for the UI would be /swagger-ui.html instead of /swagger-ui/index.html

Comment: Still i have same error

Comment: UP up up up up up up